# Terms as types in Coq

Tags: types, coq

```
Parameter R: Type.
Parameter P: R.
Parameter O: P. (*Error: The term "P" has type "R" which should be Set, Prop or Type.*)
```

doesn't work because terms can't have terms in Coq. How can we bypass this restriction? One would imagine several possibilities: parametrization, subset types, classes, records, [ensembles](https://coq.inria.fr/stdlib/Coq.Sets.Ensembles.html), explicit universe levels... My question is about the recommended and easiest way(s) of implementing terms as types in Coq (along w/ MWEs). PS. I don't assume the "recommended" and "easiest" to coincide.

A simple example would be

```
Parameter Obj: Type.
Parameter Phy Int: Obj. (*physical, intelligent*)
Parameter tree house: Phy.
```

Comment: It would be useful to have some more context to help you; what would `R`, `P` and `O` usually represent in your example?

Comment: As Arthur says it is difficult to know, specially without having more context on what your operations on the objects would be. For that mini-example, you could certainly take `Obj := Type`

Comment: I am hoping for generic MWEs for containment hierarchies (like in the example)

Comment: @ejgallego: Thanks -- I wasn't aware of the possibility `Definition Obj := Type.` Of course, this isn't a generic solution, as it only shifts the problem to the next level -- unless we can specify the universe level of the `Type`. Is this possible?

Comment: I guess you could go and play with universes, but keep in mind that `Type` is huge! You can put a lot of things inside `Type`, but that power doesn't come for free. What is a MWE? A "containment hierarchy" sounds a lot to me like a tree.

Comment: @ejgallego: Minimal working example. I suppose it is a tree (w/ nodes as types and terms, edges as `:`, and a distinguished node for the top universe). This interpretation describes any typing system

Comment: Any _consistent_ typing system

Comment: @jaam depending on what operations you'd like to do with that hiearchy, you'd have many options. Indeed a popular one is to define a type of all such hierarchies as an inductive (with constructors node, etc...) Then you could interpretet elements of that datatype into types of the CIC.

Comment: @ejgallego: You should make it into an answer

Comment: @jaam, umm, I am a bit reluctant to make an answer out of this. I am not sure how well this solution will work in the long term. As I mentioned, you could imagine `Type` as a very large set, so `x : Type` means `x` is an element of that super large set. This will indeed turn out to be more general that you usually want. Now, anything can be an `Obj`, and as such, you can prove little about them! A possible path forward is to use your current encoding and advance until you reach the first interesting theorem you want to prove about your representations. That should give us a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

An answer based on a suggestion and subsequent semi-refutation @ejgallego:

```
Let Obj := Type.
Let Phy:Obj := Type.
Let tree:Phy := Type.
Parameter house branch leaf: Phy.  
Let oak:tree := Type.
Let moldyoak:oak := Type.
Parameter moldyoak1:moldyoak.
Parameter moldyoak11:moldyoak1.
```

The solution is consistent but unsound:

```
Check nat:moldyoak. (*(nat:moldyoak) : moldyoak*)
```

So we're looking for another one