# Coq: unequal and hierarchically unrelated universes

Tags: types, coq

Is there a way to tell Coq that 2 universes are not equal, *without* stipulating a hierarchy (e.g. w/ `Universe A B. Constraint A < B.`) between them? What I have in mind is something like a `<>` relation. One frequently wants to declare universes which are neither equal nor ordered (although Coq's internal representation probably has them only in this way)

Comment: There is a deep reason universes are always comparable, do you have a concrete example of "One frequently wants to declare universes which are neither equal nor ordered" I have a lot of trouble seeing that.

Comment: @ejgallego: E.g. when one has `A < B` and `A < C` and he wants `B` and `C` to be unrelated. Or two unrelated hierarchies `A < B` and `C < D`. Or unrelated universes `A` and `B`. This would be feasible if there were a possibility of defining universes in unrelated sets. One might even think of an optional possibility of making connections (e.g. w/ `<`) between the members of distinct sets later. Of course, the latter would put Coq's type checker under lot of pressure, so maybe not (or only if it were very limited)

Comment: @ejgallego: As to why one would need unrelated universes instead of just types, the depth (2) of Coq's term : type : sort hierarchy doesn't support deeper hierarchies w/out additional tricks (like declaring universes, functions landing on sorts, etc. -- cf. http://stackoverflow.com/q/38313727/4967226)

Comment: @ejgallego I'm curious, what are the deep reasons?  In Voevodsky's HTS, I think you could consider having "univalent universe variables" and "strict universe variables" and carry all of your information about strictness vs univalentness in universe variables, and then you'd have incomparable universes, I think (though I may be wrong).

Comment: @JasonGrossI am not expert but AFAIK most models assume "strict" stratification. I dunno what would break if not.